# GAE - "Connection failed: Unknown database" on local server

Tags: google-app-engine

I can connect to and query my db on my app, but I can't on my local server. I know it is authenticating correctly because if I misspell the user or password, I get an access denied error. My code is:

```
<?php 
$servername = "173.194.xxx.xxx";
$username = "admin";
$password = "mypassw0rd";
$dbname = "dev";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(null, $username, $password, $dbname, null, "/cloudsql/myappname:mydbinstance");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Which returns:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'dev' in C:\Users\myusername\myfolder\dbconnect.php on line 9
Connection failed: Unknown database 'dev'
```

But it's fine online! Any ideas?

Comment: btw, the instance and db name are the same - "dev"

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/) say, "You do not use the "/cloudsql/"-based connection string to connect to a Cloud SQL instance if your App Engine app is running locally in the Development Server."

So, `"/cloudsql/myappname:mydbinstance"` is fine when you're running on appspot, but **not** when you're running locally in the development server: in that case, it should be the `$servername` (the public IP of the Cloud SQL instance -- I assume with real numbers rather than `xxx`, pointing this out just because you're setting but not using it in your snippet so it's not certain that you actually set it correctly) followed of course by `:3306` to specify the port.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've tried your advice with no luck. I'm now using `$conn = new mysqli(null, $username, $password, $dbname, null, $servername . ":3306/myappname:mydbinstance");`. I've also tried a slash before `$servername` and without the port number. Interestingly, misspelling my app or instance name gives the same error so I don't think it is connecting to the instance to determine that "dev" doesn't exist. Any other ideas?

Comment: I did some research and I realised my mysqli arguments were wrong. This got me working locally: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306, "/". $servername . "/myappname:mydbinstance");`

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, but I don't want to mark it as the answer if it's not best practice:

```
if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]=="::1"){
    echo 'local';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306, "/173.194.xxx.xxx/myappname:mydbinstance");
}else{
    $local = False;
    echo 'app engine';
    $conn = new mysqli(null, $username, $password, $dbname, null, "/cloudsql/myappname:mydbinstance");
}
```

Basically, I can't yet use the same code for both environments so I'm using different connection strings for each environment.

Comment: The general idea of using different connections depending on the environment is correct. However https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/ recomments the 6-argument for only when running non-locally, the 4-argument form when running locally (I'm not sure about the trade-offs, sorry).